# How to install ZF2 component without Composer

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have tried to install both ZendPdf and TCPDF into ZF2 using Composer without success. 
Software is installed and autoload files are written but nothing works, ZF can't see them.

Which files do I need to edit in order to manually install TCPDF library so that it autoloads? 
I have found lots of similar questions in StackOverflow but not many working answers that don't involve Composer.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you don't install them without Composer. I think it is easier to make Composer work than to install them by hand.

In theory you could install them by hand. Just download both components in a version you like. Then look into their `composer.json` file if you need to download some more software these libs need. Download them as well. Have a look in their `composer.json` to download even more software.

After these downloads, unpack the packages, create a whole directory tree of files, and create the autoloading manually. Which means again you have to look at all the `composer.json` files for the definition of autoloading. You are lucky if you find PSR-0 or PSR-4 autoloading, and you have to manually scan EVERY file in the directory if you have classmap autoloading.

You then simply push all these definitions into your own autoloader and hope it works.

Done. That was easy... NOT!

I can help you get Composer to work, but I cannot help you NOT use Composer. Ask a new question describing your problem using Composer.

Comment: I get your point Sven. The problem is that after installing with Composer ZF2 doesn't autoload the class (TCPDF). Right now I'm just including the class and getting on with the job as I have deadlines to meet. Not "correct" but it works. Will explore the intricacies of Composer and autoloading when I have more time.

Comment: Are you including the composer autoloader somewhere (early) in your app? https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading - it's one line of code, and if you're not familiar with composer that might be the only piece of the puzzle missing.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these instruction below to install Zend without composer. But I recommend to use composer for future consistency

1. Download latest stable copy of ZF2 from http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest and unpack, we call it "ZF2"
2. Download latest stable copy of ZF2 skeleton app from https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/ and unpack, we call it ZF2Skeleton
3. Create folder like /vendor/ZF2
4. Now copy ZF2/* into /vendor/ZF2
5. Now you need to fix ZF2_PATH or $zf2Path variable at “/init_autoloader.php” file of root to point our “/vendor/ZF2” folder. Find "$zf2Path = false;" line into "/init_autoloader.php" file and replace it by "$zf2Path = 'vendor/ZF2/library';"

That's all. You may visit https://shkhan.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/install-zend-framework-2-into-windows-iis/ for more information about installing ZF2 without composer.